# How do I search an image with specific resolution using new Google Image Search

Tags: google-image-search

As you know, there was an option available in Google Image Search known as Search image with specific screen resolution, option name as `Exactly` but recently Google changed the approach and am not happy with the pre-defined sizes available there, any idea how I can hunt for a specific resolution image?

Say what if I want to search for an image of `300x300`

Screen of new Google Image Search Options...

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the option got removed, and Google have even [acknowledged it](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/websearch/KlE_vtKp2cs/y7RAKb1EiZcJ):

> Thanks for writing in. We're aware of this issue, and we're working on
>   bringing the feature back. I'll let you know as soon as it's back up.
>   Sorry for any inconvenience

As pointed out in that thread, you can still get an exact size by using the `imagesize` filter like so:

```
html5 logo imagesize:300x300
```

Answer (score 0):

Google has now made the option available, steps to follow :

[images.google.com](http://images.google.com/) -> Search Tools -> Size -> Select Exactly Option

[image]